# Does Merge take Order by into account when updating

Tags: oracle, order-by, merge

I have to merge a subquery result into table A. Here's the basic merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO A
 USING (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,LAST_LOGIN_DATE) B ON A.CUSTOMER_ID=B.CUSTOMER_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET A.LAST_LOGIN_DATE=B.LAST_LOGIN_DATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT(CUSTOMER_ID,LAST_LOGIN_DATE)
   VALUES(B.CUSTOMER_ID,B.LAST_LOGIN_DATE);
```

Now, there might be multiple entries for one customer_id value in the table B. I need the latest date to be updated into the table A. I wonder, if I order the result by last_login_date column in Ascending  order, will the merge statement eventually update the record in A with the latest last_login_date?

Comment: Let's do something curious: let's look at the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/MERGE.htm#SQLRF01606): "MERGE is a deterministic statement. You cannot update the same row of the target table multiple times in the same MERGE statement."

Comment: Why don't you test your statement. You can sort ascending and descending.

Comment: Then, let's put it another way. If I change the order to DESC, then will pick the first one?

Comment: No, it won't. You need to change the inner select to make sure it only returns unique `customer_id` values. See here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle+greatest-n-per-group or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+greatest-n-per-group  for many answers to that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle `MERGE` cannot update the same row more than once. If you attempt that you will get the following error:

> ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

That means that the order of the rows in the `USING` clause does not matter. You are not able to use the order of the rows to influence what ends up in the target table after the `MERGE` is complete.

Instead, adjust your `USING` clause so that you only return one row per `CUSTOMER_ID`. Keep in mind that you can write a complex query in the `USING` clause if you need to. For your example query, this could be as simple as something like the following:

```
MERGE INTO A
USING 
 (
  SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, MAX(LAST_LOGIN_DATE) LAST_LOGIN_DATE
  FROM
  ...
  GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
) B ON A.CUSTOMER_ID=B.CUSTOMER_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET A.LAST_LOGIN_DATE=B.LAST_LOGIN_DATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT(CUSTOMER_ID,LAST_LOGIN_DATE)
   VALUES(B.CUSTOMER_ID,B.LAST_LOGIN_DATE);
```

Comment: Yeah, in fact I do exactly the same thing. Just the thing is, when MAXing the last_login_Date, the query takes long, so I thought I could order that column in ascending order and get the latest one eventually :)